# When using the Data Pipeline to backup a DynamoDB table, does readThroughputPercent account for autoscaling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-data-pipeline

Suppose I set my DDB table to autoscale over 80%, and set the backup data pipeline to `0.85`.

Does the pipeline use the read throughput it determined initially, or does it scale up along with the table?